# Jquery event on photo view position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of photos in my webpage, I need to fire a jquery event when a photo is on a particular position (view port)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried $('#element').visible(), or checking the coordinates using .position() ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rect = document.getElementbyID('myId').getBoundingClientRect();
// You can access the rect attributes by using the code below, this gives you cordinates as per the view port.
var t = rect.top
var l = rect.left
var width = rect.width;
var height = rect.height;


// if you need the coordinates as per the absolute screen then you can do somehting like this 
var left = l + window.screenX; 
var top = t + window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight);
var right = left + width;
var bottom = top + height;
```

Comment: In my case i have more than 5 images how will i work this for all images ?

Comment: Calculate for each image seperately the cordinates and then match whether that is the place you need the image or not.

Comment: @Abbas i need Exactly the functionality like scroll on  i need to add photo id in url like below 

http://www.ndtv.com/photos/news/pm-modi-inaugurates-afghan-india-friendship-dam-22168#photo-279556

Comment: Those i think are preloaded images, for that you dont need to calculate position or something. I think your question is not relevant what you desire to achieve.